# Issue installing an npm package directly from Github

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a React common project that I am trying to include in another React project (the 'base' project).  I named the test project like so in the package.json file and committed it to Github:

```
{
  "name": "NPM-From-Git-Test",
  "version": "5.0.0",
  "description": "Trying to create a common React project and add it from github",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3"
  },
```

Next I ran an npm install with the web address of the github project.

```
npm install git+https://myAddress/TestCommon
```

It installed and created a project folder in the node_modules folder named 'NPM-From-Git-Test'

Next I included the component 'ExamplePageOne' that I need in the 'base' project like so:

```
import {ExamplePageOne} from 'NPM-From-Git-Test';
```

The intellisense tells me that the 'NPM-From-Git-Test' Module is not installed, and when I start the dev server, I get the error 'Cannot resolve module 'NPM-From-Git-Test'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's the case of the name? I know NPM is kind of picky about that. It wants only lower case characters in the name.

Comment: Good call out.  I was really hoping this would fix it.  The same error of 'Cannot Resolve Module' does not budge no matter what I try.

Comment: I got this done by using git's submodule command.  It was super simple once I decided to give it a try...

Answer (score 1):

In NPM-From-Git-Test are you using `export` or `export default` to export ExamplePageOne? If you are using `export default`, you'll want to do:

`import ExamplePageOne from 'NPM-From-Git-Test';`

If you *are* using `export`, make sure that you are spelling `ExamplePageOne` exactly as you are in NPM-From-Git-Test's export.

More on ES6 imports and exports: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: Good callout.  I ensured that the exports have the right syntax.  Still cant shake this error:  "Module not found: Error:  Cannot resolve module 'npm-from-git-test' in c:/<mypath> @.src/<mypath>"

Answer (score 0):

I found I got this error with npm 6, but upgrading to npm 7 resolved it.